# Explain reduction in throughput at 802.11

Tags: wifi

Actual throughput is lower than physical layer transmission rate
Decrease.

What is the relevance of the 11a MAC to this speed reduction?

Answer (score 0):

Are you comparing the Transmission rate of 802.11 and Application throughput (For example, Iperf result)?

If yes, 
First of all, the transmission rate is counting with the MAC layer of the packet including  802.11 headers. The length counting for a single data packet size is already different.

More important, 802.11 is a CSMA/CA protocol that depends on the airtime for transmitting the packets. Exact management packet (block ACK, RTS/CTS, ... )or time waiting (for example, SIFS / Contention Window, ...) are needed for this mechanism. This used up the airtime so that the actual throughput will be slightly lower than the transmission rate.